# function inside C loop condition

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, compiler-optimization

I can have something like:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < get_length(object); ++i) {
   ...
}
```

where I know for sure that get_length(object) will not change during the loop lifetime, or I can convert it to:

```
const unsigned length = get_length(object);
for (unsigned i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
   ...
}
```

Maybe oftentimes the compiler can't know for sure whether `get_length(object)` will indeed not change, so it will evaluate it at every loop, so probably the second form is better, although it is more cumbersome to the eye?

Comment: To me, the second form is easier to read, because with the first form, I ask exactly the same question: will the result of this function really be constant or not?

Comment: I don't find the 2nd _"more cumbersome to the eye"_. Since it is also more efficient I don't see a reason to use the 1st option.

Comment: If the function is defined (implemented) in the same [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) the compiler *might* be able to deduce if its returned value can be cached or not, or at least the call might be able to be inlined. But otherwise it will be called for each iteration, which can be a little wasteful.

Comment: "although it is more cumbersome to the eye"  Breaking expressions up in several lines is _less_ cumbersome to the eye. Beware of those who are insisting on writing everything on a single line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is debatable whether the first or second form is easiest on the eye.

In any case, with the second form, we make sure that the compiler will only call `get_length()` once. I guess that most experienced programmers will prefer this form if the function is indeed intended to return a constant for the duration of the loop, because the second form conveys this assumption by itself.

In the first form, the compiler might in simple cases be able to deduce that `get_length()` will be constant and thus only call it once. However, it seems at least GCC is not that smart yet. [Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/njevTMj6a) with optimization level `-O3`.

The linked assembler code may be a bit difficult to read, but in `f1`, notice that instruction `jne .L15` in line 37 which jumps to line 21 which is the beginning of the inlined code corresponding to my example implementation of `get_length()`. Thus the code corresponding to `get_length()` is in this case executed for every iteration of the loop.

Perhaps the compiler could better optimize an even simpler example or a future version of the compiler or a different compiler could optimize this example. In any case, by using the second form we can avoid such speculation and having to look into compiled assembly code.

This example and analysis should illustrate the benefit of the second form.

Comment: Your example certainly didn't make it easy for GCC!  You made your string global variable non-`const`, and inside the loop you call a non-inline function you didn't even prototype (`printf`).  Even with GCC treating printf as `__builtin_printf`, it doesn't have special support for knowing it can assume that your own global variables aren't modified by it despite the fact that it's not `__attribute__((pure))`.  (Because that's not true; you can call other functions to use your own buffer for stdout, among other things.)

Comment: So anyway, the optimization was not really *missed* in your example, good reasons why GCC doesn't!  But if you use `const char *const object = "Hello";`, then GCC should know `object` can't change across iterations even across a call to an arbitrary function. 
 But that still doesn't help, GCC still scans it inside the loop, not figuring out that `get_length` is `pure`.  But `const object` is sufficient for clang to constant-propagate through it at compile time: https://godbolt.org/z/dzEz3jr9h

Comment: @PeterCordes You are right, the example is not as simple for a compiler as it may seem. This only underlines the main point: in this case we can do a bit more typing in the source code to avoid all these considerations and investigations. It is a case of keeping it simple the right way. My answer should not be seen as a criticism of the GCC compiler which I appreciate very much.

Comment: (Is there a middle ground, where you can tell the compiler enough to let it think some pointed-to `const char *` is loop-invariant but where it doesn't see the actual definition to evaluate `get_length` to a constant at compile time?  Yes in theory with `extern const char object[];`, but in that case GCC and clang miss the optimization: they scan the array inside the printf loop instead of before. https://godbolt.org/z/84x4P1Meh)

Comment: 100% agreed that people should write the second form if they care at all about efficiency; it's idiomatic in C because we can't count on compilers to hoist stuff like that.  I was mostly commenting to suggest correcting the phrasing since you're actually demonstrating a case that can't safely/correctly be optimized at all.  (I'm pretty sure compilers would have a much easier time hoisting a `return p->length` rather than a search loop; some `const` and/or a lack of non-inline function calls in the loop would do the trick then.)

Answer (score 2):

I would generally render it as:

```c
for (unsigned i = 0, length = get_length(); i < length; ++i) {
   ...
}
```

…which is mildly more self-documenting and keeps the outer scope clean. But this really is an unnecessary micro-optimization in most cases, and in many cases the compiler can already figure out it can hoist the call out of the loop, particularly if you’ve done pointer restriction properly and have the definition of `get_length` somewhere it can be inlined.

Comment: `get_length` could be anything from an inlined function the compiler knows about to an external library call the compiler has no clue of. So the micro-optimisation might not be one.

Comment: Yes, hence the 'most'. The takeaway is to know what your code is doing.

Comment: See discussion in comments under nielsen's answer - it doesn't take much to stop a compiler from seeing that something is loop-invariant. One non-inline function call would do it even if `get_length(const foo *p)` is `return p->length` or something.  Or if it's actually a search loop for an implicit-length array GCC/Clang won't hoist the search loop. (Like nielsen's answer, which now that I think of it is actually horrible and not very plausible; you should be iterating over the array checking for the terminator as you go, instead of treating it like explicit-length.)

Answer (score 2):

The second form is probably better indeed - I'll try to explain why while we peek a bit closer to the various forms of optimizations that might occur here.

Assuming we have `for (unsigned i = 0; i < get_length(object); ++i)` where `get_length` doesn't modify anything and where the result will always be the same integer constant, then:

- An optimization replacing the function call with a hard-coded number is desirable here.
- Or if that can't be done because the number is calculated in run-time, we'd like the program to only call the function once.
- We *don't* want the program to pointlessly call the function over and over since that will be very slow.

Historically, compilers were really bad here and so traditional good practice back in the days was *always* to move the function call above the loop. Older C programming books will definitely tell you as much. But it *is* still good practice today, because we might not always be able to rely on optimizations.

Lets start off with an example that yields the most desired "hard-coded number" optimization:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
  size_t length;
} obj_t;

size_t get_length (const obj_t* obj)
{
  return obj->length;
}

int main (void)
{
  obj_t object = { 5 };
  for (size_t i = 0; i<get_length(&object); ++i)
  {
    puts("hello world");
  }
}
```

We can check out the generated assembler with maximum optimization (`gcc -O3`) in Godbolt here: https://godbolt.org/z/9GnrEGvxc. The relevant part being `mov ebx, 5`. The compiler completely ignored the struct, the function, the function call, everything. It just stored the value 5 in a CPU register and then called `puts` for as many times as that number. That's very efficient code.

Now lets block the optimizer a bit by making the number 5 something passed on to the program in run-time:

```c
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) // I'll pass "5" in argv
{
// quick and dirty string-to-int conversion:
  obj_t object = { argv[1][0]-'0' };
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4Mcjsha5d. Now the compiler has to actually load the value from command line arguments. But it's still quite cocky because it noticed that it can just save that read number in a register for later - there is still no `call get_length` anywhere. When this optimization happens, we say that the function was *inlined*. Because essentially the whole thing that the function does (in the Godbolt disassembly `mov rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]`) was inserted on the caller side instead (`mov rax...` save 'rax' for later).

As we can see so far, it doesn't matter the slightest where we put the function call because the compiler is acting smart still. We'll have to write a much more inefficient program to yield an actual function call. For example we could move the function and struct variable to another .c file.

In this case I'm gonna cheat and just disable function inlining through gcc non-standard function attributes, while still leaving all other optimizations on with `-O3`. https://godbolt.org/z/j3WPscxWq Finally defeated, the compiler is forced to generate bad code with the actual function call. The for loop getting translated to:

```
.L5:
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        add     rbx, 1
        call    puts
.L4:
        lea     rdi, [rsp+8]
        call    get_length
        cmp     rbx, rax
        jb      .L5
```

And now with inlining gone, we notice that indeed it calls `get_length` every lap of the loop. This will happen whenever the compiler can neither determine the outcome of the function at compile-time nor perform inlining by grabbing the function's body and insert it in the caller code. Which typically happens when the function is located in another .c file compiled separately.

We may have expected it to only call the function once, but that optimization didn't happen either. As noted in comments below another answer, the gcc compiler specifically fails to optimize this for whatever reason, whereas the clang compiler optimized it to only call the function once. Clearly we can't *rely* on the compiler optimization here, as results will be different in different compilers and compiler ports.

At this point, moving `get_length` out of the loop will yield much better results. https://godbolt.org/z/f6dEGMfrn. The function is called just once, the results of the call stored in a register `mov rbp, rax`, `i` is stored in another register and the registers are compared each lap of the loop `cmp rbp, rbx`.

And now we have proven that the second form is indeed much more efficient, but only when the compiler cannot inline the function or determine the outcome in advance.

We should note however that common standard library functions like `strlen` or `memcpy` etc are very likely going to get inlined efficiently by the compiler. So them old C books telling you to move `strlen` specifically out of the loop condition are outdated. Whenever in doubt, disassemble and look for `call strlen` instructions - you don't even need to know assembler.

Comment: The case where clang optimized but GCC didn't was a case of fully optimizing away the function and replacing it with a compile-time constant, not a loop-invariant runtime variable.  https://godbolt.org/z/63x1qTGcM  - `get_length` is a loop over a string, a hand-written `strlen`, so getting to a compile-time constant requires compile-time eval of enough loop iterations to reach the end.  Probably tweaking some GCC heuristics could get it to look farther.  Making the string shorter, GCC succeeds with a two-byte string (including the terminating `0`) like `"H"` https://godbolt.org/z/voY1vWdhn

Comment: *So them old C books telling you to move `strlen` specifically out of the loop condition are outdated* - if you call any functions in the loop that could possibly modify the contents of the buffer you're calling `strlen` on, the compiler must not optimize since storing a `0` anywhere could change the result.  So it's still good advice unless you're working with a local `char buf[]` whose address never escapes this function, which is unlikely, or if your loop doesn't call any functions and doesn't write to the buffer.

Comment: @PeterCordes Not only that, in my very simple "getter" function from this answer, just returning an int member of a struct, the latest gcc failed to optimize it when I turned off inlining. Whereas the latest clang optimizes it to a single call. Older versions of clang fail to optimize it to a single call as well. I suspect it has something to do with assumptions about internal/external linkage somehow. Anyway for the sake of this answer it is good that it failed, since that demonstrates that we shouldn't rely blindly on the compiler's optimizer.

Comment: That is surprising.  In GCC, `__attribute__((noinline))` is separate from `__attribute__((noipa))` (which would disable all inter-procedural analysis, making it a black-box like if it was in another compilation unit without LTO).  But Clang doesn't have a separate attribute that I know of.  So I'd have guessed that `noinline` might disable more for clang than for GCC.  But it's bit artificial: normally it can either see that tiny function and inline it, or it can only see a prototype. `__attribute__((const))` works with a prototype, or with noinline: https://godbolt.org/z/n5sGeGabv

Comment: `gcc -O3 -fno-inline` also disables inlining even for tiny functions, without needing attributes.  https://godbolt.org/z/5bYGeKEvT shows GCC still calling inside the loop, not inferring `__attribute__((const))`, but clang does.  Same if we change `main` to `foo`, in case GCC's implicit `__attribute__((cold))` on main was hurting optimization.  So yeah, GCC is indeed worse at optimizing in cases where it doesn't inline.